# Why does this error say I pass two arguments into destroy() even though I only pass one?

Tags: python, tkinter

Below is my minimal reproducible code as well as the error message. I only pass one argument into `destroy()`, but the error message says I pass two arguments instead. What's going on?

#### Minimal Reproducible Code

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

class Test(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=100, height=100)
        self.label = tk.Label(self.canvas)
        self.canvas.destroy(self.label)

test = Test()
```

#### Error Message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\brian\Documents\Projects\pysnake\test.py", line 12, in <module>
    test = Test()
  File "C:\Users\brian\Documents\Projects\pysnake\test.py", line 10, in __init__
    self.canvas.destroy(self.label)
TypeError: destroy() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: `self.canvas.destroy(self.label)` is the same as `tk.Canvas.destroy(self.canvas, self.label)` and `tk.Canvas.destroy` only takes in 1 parameter `self`. Also what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @TheLizzard I'm trying to destroy the label.

Comment: For instance methods, the first positional argument is `self`.

Comment: @BrianZhang `self.label.destroy()`??

Comment: ahhhh I have to call with tk.Canvas.destroy(), I thought I had to call destroy through the parent widget, my bad.

Comment: @TheLizzard Ohhhhhhh I thought I had to call through parent you're right mb.

Comment: I misunderstood the docs.

Comment: @BrianZhang: no, you do not have to call with `tk.Canvas.destroy()`. Don't do that. Just call `destroy` on whatever widget you wish to destroy. For example, `self.label.destroy()`.